# List files from a static folder in FastAPI

Tags: filesystems, fastapi

I know how to serve static files in FastAPI using [StaticFiles](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/), how can I enable
directory listing like in Apache web server?

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI(...)

app.mount("/samples", StaticFiles(directory='samples'), name="samples")

# GET http://localhost:8000/samples/path/to/file.jpg -> OK
# GET http://localhost:8000/samples -> not found error
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, but maybe putting a reverse proxy such as nginx to serve static content can help

Comment: It can be as simple as this https://github.com/wemadefree/webook-fastapi/blob/main/nginx/nginx.conf#L18-L28

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure FastAPI/Starlette exposes functionality to do that out of the box.

But it shouldn't be too hard to implement something yourself. This could be a starting point:

```py
import os
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")


templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/static", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def list_files(request: Request):

    files = os.listdir("./static")
    files_paths = sorted([f"{request.url._url}/{f}" for f in files])
    print(files_paths)
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "list_files.html", {"request": request, "files": files_paths}
    )
```

list_files.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Files</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Files:</h1>
    <ul>
      {% for file in files %}
      <li><a href="{{file}}">{{file}}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you hit `/static` you would see:

[image]

---

### Additional notes

Note that `list_files.html` is an html template and should sit in the directory `templates/` as @Michel Hua pertinently mentioned in his comment. For more info on templates check the [templates docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, beware list_files.html should be in templates/ folder.